# how to graph hours in axis 'y' python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have two columns in a data frame, D and E, where D are the values in 'HH:MM:SS' and E are int values corresponding D. And I want to plot in the axis Y the hours and de axis X the int values. I'm doing this with matplotlib but they are not sorted and each value is on the y axis.

My code is like that:

```
elementosx =dftunels['E']  
elementosy = dftunels['D']  
plt.scatter(elementosx, elementosy)
plt.xticks(elementosx)
plt.plot(elementosx,elementosy)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: try `elementosy = pd.to_timedelta(dftunels['D'] )`.

Comment: doesn´t work :( TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') according to the rule 'same_kind'

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use seaborn like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x='E',y= 'D',data = dftunels)
```

[image: seaborn plot]
But you can of course do it with matplotlib also

```
plt.plot(dftunels['E'],dftunels['D'], 'o')
```

[image: matplot plot]